# How to prolong token expire date after each request(i use WebApi bearer token)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, access-token

The problem:

- I have ASP WebApi 2 with default Asp identity(bearer)
- Client platforms - Ios,Android,WinPhone and Web

Expire date for Ios,Android,WinPhone must be 1 year, but for Web - 5 minuts, and expire date must prolong after each user activity

Each request can contains PlatformType(or other info)

How prolong token expire date after each user activity?

Comment: How are you creating the token at present?

Comment: Like this - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a **Refresh Token** when your main token has expired. This refresh token can have an expiration date of many days, your choice.

```cs
RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider()
            {
                OnCreate = (obj) =>
                {
                    obj.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(6);
                    obj.SetToken(obj.SerializeTicket());
                },
                OnReceive = (obj) => { obj.DeserializeTicket(obj.Token); }
            },
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't prolong even when the user is performing a activity, token expires while the user does submit a sample request! I don't want to set the `expiresUtc` to more then one minute

Comment: When the token expires, you need to create a new one with 'grant_type' = 'refresh_token' and with the 'refresh_token' that was given when you generated your first token. The token is short-lived, and the refresh token could last 2 weeks for example.